# libACE with gcc linking

Tags: c++, gcc

i am having a problem while compiling the code exemple in this link on debian OS :
http://touch-base.com/documentation/API-GettingStarted.htm
and this is the result :

```
user@debian:~/Téléchargements/touchscreen$ g++ main.cpp libACE-5.6.3.so libtbapi.so -lX11
    libtbapi.so: undefined reference to `ACE_Reactor::instance(ACE_Reactor*, int)'
    libtbapi.so: undefined reference to `ACE_Task_Base::activate(long, int, int, long, int, ACE_Task_Base*, unsigned long*, void**, unsigned long*, unsigned long*)'
    libtbapi.so: undefined reference to `XineramaQueryScreens'
    libtbapi.so: undefined reference to `XineramaIsActive'
    libtbapi.so: undefined reference to `ACE_OS::thr_create(void* (*)(void*), void*, long, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, long, void*, unsigned long, ACE_Base_Thread_Adapter*)'
    libtbapi.so: undefined reference to `ACE_Reactor::ACE_Reactor(ACE_Reactor_Impl*, int)'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem "undefined reference to...", I summed up several situations in c/c++. Wish it can help you to solve your problem

1.lack of *.o

eg:

[image]

gcc -c test.c

```
gcc -c main.c
```

if do this gcc -o main main.o

"undefined ference to" will come up

so we should do like this : gcc -o main main.o test.o

2.lack of  *.a/*.so

[image]

gcc -c test.c

gcc -rc test.a test.o

gcc -c main.c

then if we : gcc -o main main.o

this error will come up we can use this :gcc -o main main.o ./test.a //./is the position of test.a

3.
 this is not easy to find out.  When you link library files, you also used another library file

4.the order of library link

5.others like C++ link C library.......